# Calculations In PHP

Tags: php, joomla

I am needing to perform a calculation and round the results all in my php.  I have tried the below but I always end up with a 0.  Which if I manually perform the calculation should not be the case.  Below is my syntax and what I am after is

```
val1-val2
answer from above / val1
answer from above * 100 (to get percent)
```

Here is the syntax I use

```
print "<td>" . number_format(round($res->val1-$res->val2/$res->val1)*100) . "%" . "</td>";
```

**edit**
Let's use real life example
$val1 = 1122
$val2 = 280

I want the calculation steps to be $val1-$val2 = 842

Then 842/$val1 or 842/1122 = .75

If I use 
($val1-$val2)/$val1 = 1 which is incorrect.

Comment: Integer division. Either cast to floats or first multiply by 100, then divide if you want to keep it as integer.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen - can you show example?

Comment: Move the *100 before /, it's that simple. Also the code you included is missing parentheses

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen - no need for added parens or anything?

Comment: Have you considered the manual? http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo round((($val1 - $val2) / $val1) * 100).'%';
```

Works fine? See here https://3v4l.org/d4bpe

Comment: Yes, if I break it out into multiple lines it works.  I was looking for a one %liner in php that could get me the result of

Answer (score 1):

Use (val1-val2)/val1
Note the bracket!

Comment: what about the multiplication?

Comment: Multiplication is commutative, you do not need additional bracketing.
(val1-val2)/val1*100 === ((val1-val2)/val1)*100

Comment: Something is still awry - let's take real scenario.  If val1 = 1122 and val2 = 280 if I  use (1122-280)/1122 that produces 1.  My desired value is .75 bc I want it to be 1122-280=842 then 842/1122 = .75

Comment: You mistyped something. (1122-280)/1122 = 0.75, not 1
Edit: Okay, now I see. You have the problem with the round(). Use round($variable, $precision).

Comment: i do not follow your round($variable, $precision) comment.

Comment: number_format(round(($res->val1-$res->val2)/$res->val1,2)*100)